# CircuitBreaker CLOSED notification

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a route reading from a queue `from("jms:xx")`. On the route I call an external webservice. I also configure a CircuitBreaker in case the webservice is temporary unavailable. 
When the CircuitBreaker opens, all new incoming requests are blocked (status OPEN).

Something that puzzles me: in case of an error, the message needs to be put back on the queue, preferably with a delay (thanks to redelivery policies).
I assume the CircuitBreaker is not in touch with the messagelistener so even when the CircuitBreaker is OPEN, it will still regularly receive all messages from the input queue.

To reduce this overhead I would like to :
move all incoming messages to the DLQ when a RejectedExecutionException is thrown. Once the connection problem is resolved (status becomes CLOSED again)  all these messages (header filter) can be moved again to the processing queue.
I understand I have a risk here: It will only retry when new messages arrive.

My Question: Is it possible to get informed when the status changes from HALF_OPEN to CLOSED (f.e. `onClosed`) ?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use. And do you use hystrix as circuit breaker or the deprecated load balancer based circuit breaker?

Comment: Also maybe consider suspending/resuming the JMS route based on the circuit breaker state so you don't keep routing from JMS when the circuit breaker is not closed.

Comment: I'm currently using Camel version 2.17.2. I only looked at the loadbalancer's circuit breaker. I was not aware it is deprecated.

Comment: I like the idea of the controlbus. Never looked at it in detail. Can I call "controlbus:suspend?routeId=route1" within the onException(RejectedExecutionException) flow of route1 itself ?

Comment: Yeah its just a Camel endpoint so you can call it anywhere where you can use endpoints. You may want to use async=true to not block while the route is being stopped etc.